# XNA Adding Craters (via GPU) with a "Burn" Effect

Tags: xna, effects, textures

I am currently working on a 2D "Worms" clone in XNA, and one of the features is "deformable" terrain (e.g. when a rocket hits the terrain, there is an explosion and a chunk of the terrain disappears).

How I am currently doing this is by using a texture that has a progressively higher Red value as it approaches the center. I cycle through every pixel of that "Deform" texture, and if the current pixel overlaps a terrain pixel and has a high enough red value, I modify the color array representing the terrain to transparent. If the current pixel does NOT have a high enough Red value, I blacken the terrain color (it gets blacker the closer the Red value is to the threshold). At the end of this operation I use SetData to update my terrain texture.

I realize this is not a good way to do it, not only because I have read about pipeline stalls and such, but also because it can become quite laggy if lots of craters are being added at the same time. I want to remake my Crater Generation on the GPU instead using Render Targets "ping-ponging" between being the target and the texture to modify. That isn't the problem, I know how to do that. the problem is I don't know how to keep my burn effect using this method.

Here's how the burn effect looks right now:

[image: Burn Effect]

Does anybody have an idea how I would create a similar burn effect (darkening the edges around the formed crater)? I am completely unfamiliar with Shaders but if it requires it I would be really thankful if someone walked me through on how to do it. If there are any other ways that'd be great too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're good in the right way. But you're doing a lot of things by hand, which can also be done by just drawing sprites and applying the right formulas.

*For example:*
Suppose your terrain is saved into a giant texture in the alpha channel of the texture. 1 is terrain, 0 is nothing.

An explosion happens and the terrain has to be deformed. Update your texture easily by just drawing a black transparent sphere (or explosion area) onto your texture. The terrain is gone, because the alpha value is 0 of the black sphere. Your texture is now up to date, everything was done by the spriteBatch. And nothing had to be checked.

I don't know if you wanted a solution for this as well, but now you have one.

*For the burn effect*
Now that we have our terrain in a texture, we can do a post effect on the drawing by using a shader (just like you said). The shader obtains the texture's alpha channel and can now do different things to get our burn effect.

1. The first option is to do edge detection. Check a few pixels in all 4 directions and see if the pixel is at the edge. If so, it needs to do a burn by, for example, multiplying it with the distance to the edge (or any other function you like)
2. Another way is quite similar to the first one, but does it in two steps. First you do the same kind of edge detection, but you save the edges in a seperate texture. Now, when you are drawing your texture, you can overlay your edges. So it's quite the same as just drawing the ground at once.

The main difference for the second option is that you can also choose to just draw your normal ground and you are not adjusting the pixel in the ground texture on rendering.

I know this is a long story, but it is a nice technique. Have a look at toon shaders, they do edge detection as well, even though it is 3D.

Keywords: Toon shading, HLSL, Post effects, edge detection, image processing.
Recommended reading: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials